# How to POST form data from dynamically created inputs?

Tags: php, post, foreach

I'm generating several dynamic inputs with a foreach. Each input gets its `name` and `id` from looping through an array from a text file.

The form data is then sent to another PHP page to perform some database queries with POST.

The problem I am facing is that each input value returns NULL.

I don't know what is going on, because when I look in the Web Console on the Network tab, I can see the Parameters are being collected.

**array.txt**

```
first_name
last_name
occupation
company_name
industry
city
country
countryCode
phone
email
address
stateProvince
postalZipeCode
```

**form.php**

```
//get array of names and ids for inputs
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('array.txt'));


//loop through the array
echo '<form method="POST" action="insert.php">';
foreach($array as $input) {
    echo '<label>'.$input.'</label>'
       . '<input type="text" id="'.$input.'" name="'.$input.'" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="'.$input.'">';  
    echo '<br>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

**Network Tab (web console)**

[image]

**insert.php**

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    //get variables
    if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $first_name= $_POST['first_name']; //1.
    }

    if (isset($_POST['last_name'])){
        $last_name=$_POST['last_name']; //2.
    }

    if (isset($_POST['occupation'])) {
        $occupation=$_POST['occupation']; //3.
    }

    if (isset($_POST['company_name'])) {
        $company_name=$_POST['company_name']; //4 
    }

    if (isset($_POST['industry'])){
        $industry = $_POST['industry']; //5
    }

    if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $city = $_POST['city']; //6
    }

    if(isset($_POST['country'])){
        $country=$_POST['country']; //7
    }

    if (isset($_POST['countryCode'])) {
        $countryCode = $_POST['countryCode']; //8
    }

    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; //9
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email']; //10
    }

    if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
        $address = $_POST['address']; //11
    }

    if (isset($_POST['stateProvince'])) {
        $stateProvince = $_POST['stateProvince']; //12
    }

    if (isset($_POST['postalZipeCode'])) {
        $postalZipeCode = $_POST['postalZipeCode']; //13
    }

    // insert into table 
    $insertProspectQuery = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, occupation, company,industry,city,country,countryCode,phone,email,address,stateProvince,postalZipeCode) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $insertProspectQuery->bind_param('sssssssssssss',$first_name,$last_name,$occupation,$company_name,$industry,$city,$country,$countryCode,$phone,$email,$address,$stateProvince,$postalZipeCode);        
    $insertProspectQuery->execute();
    $insertProspectQuery->close();
    $ok = 1;

    } else {
        //handle error
    }
```

Comment: What does `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST): die();` tell you if you use it at the top of `insert.php`?

Comment: "The problem I am facing is that each input value returns NULL" — How do you know? Your PHP assigns the values to variables and then does nothing more with it.

Comment: `echo '<label>'.$input.'</label>'` — A label is useless unless you put a form control inside it or give it a `for` attribute.

Comment: @Quentin : I do an insert in the database. And the rows all return NULL. Meaning, NULL  values are getting inserted on the table.

Comment: Then there is probably something about the insert that is wrong. You need to provide an [mcve].

Comment: Have you [**checked your PHP error logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)?

Comment: @Thisisme You should really consider providing the information which experienced programmers request of you. Add the `var_dump();` output which I requested and your life might just get a little easier.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `output which I requested and your life might just get a little easier` hahah I imagine you saying that while casually slapping an iron bar against your other hand, mafia style `;-)`

Comment: To verify what you have in php, try to put a  phpinfo(); at the start of your insert.php script. Then you'll get a dump of the $_POST array.

Comment: @F.Madsen that is entirely inappropriate.  It's overkill

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I'm debugging right now and I have found the error in the var_dump. The issue is being created with empty white space at the end of each variable. This is the var_dump `array(19) { ["first_name "]=> string(6) "John" ["last_name "]=> string(8) "Doe"[.......]`. I dont know what creates the white space in the name variables? It should be `["first_name"]` and NOT `["first_name "]`. How does this happen?

Comment: Lol at the iron bar imagery. Glad I could help you to solve your own issue. I provided an answer slightly different to yours if you wanted to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By outputing the variables with var_dump as suggested by MonkeyZeus, I have found that the issue was being created with empty white space at the end of each name variable.

This is a short summary of the var_dump : 
`array(19) { ["first_name "]=> string(6) "John" ["last_name "]=> string(8) "Doe"[.......]`.

I dont know what creates the white space in the name variables, probably the fact that the variables are being created from a text file and text file adds white space at the end of each line.

So since it should be ["first_name"] and NOT ["first_name "], `$_POST` was not able to recognize the variables being posted on `insert.php`.

This would never run in this wrong use case :

```
if(isset($_POST["first_name"])){
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
}
```

Because `["first_name"] != ["first_name "]`

I solved the problem by trimming the names variable before using them in the foreach.

Solution quick trim :

form.php

```
//get array of names and ids for inputs
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('array.txt'));

//trim post variables
$trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$array);

//loop through the array

    echo '<form method="POST" action="insert.php">';
    foreach($trimmed_array as $input) {//pass the trimmed version of name variables
        echo '<label>'.$input.'</label>'
           . '<input type="text" id="'.$input.'" name="'.$input.'" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="'.$input.'">';  
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
    echo '</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$input` in your foreach loop contains a space which it probably got from the `array.txt` file.

To avoid future issues you should just trim `$input`:

```
foreach($array as $input) {
    $input = trim($input);

    // Proceed as normal
}
```

You can choose to try and fix the data in `array.txt` but if the mistake presents itself in the future then your app will stop working again so it's best to just apply `trim()` per item retrieved from your file.